# Eigenvalues of adjugate matrix of a singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Given a singular matrix $A$, find the eigenvalues of the adjugate matrix of $A$.

The same question with $A$ being invertible is trivial since $A\operatorname{adj}A=(\operatorname{adj}A)A=(\det A) I$.

If $\operatorname{rank}A\leq n-2$, it is well-known that $\operatorname{adj}A=0$ and $0$ is the only eigenvalue.

It remains to deal with the case $\operatorname{rank}A= n-1$. It is easy to check that $\operatorname{rank}\operatorname{adj} A=1$. Hence $0$ is an eigenvalue of $\operatorname{adj} A$ with multiplicity at least $n-1$. There's at most one other eigenvalue, say $\lambda$. How can I find $\lambda$ ?

Comment: see https://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2011/01/22/eigenvalues-of-adjugate-matrix/

Comment: Alternatively, the answer is clear if you know that [the adjugate of $A$ is always a polynomial in $A$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#Characteristic_polynomial).

Comment: @user1551 Never seen that one before. Can you hint at a proof ?

Comment: Nevermind, it's merely Cayley Hamilton theorem.