# When is $adj(A)$ nilpotent?

Tags: matrices, adjoint-operators, nilpotence

Are there any conditions regarding the $adj(A)$ being nilpotent for some square matrix A?

Comment: This is nearly a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221121/eigenvalues-of-adjugate-matrix-of-a-singular-matrix